# Select label by text

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using selenium and I want to select a label based on the text of the label. Below is the html from which I want to select.

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <fieldset>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1"/> text1 </label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2"/> text2 </label>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
IList<IWebElement> element = driver.FindElements(By.Name("category"));
            foreach (IWebElement ele in element)
            {
                if (ele.Text.Contains(my text))
                {
                    ele.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But it's not selecting. How to select the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance and it seems like you're selecting the input box and not the label, its parent.

If you wish to select the parent.

```
IList<IWebElement> element = driver.FindElements(By.Name("category"));
foreach (IWebElement e in element)
{
        var parentLabel = e.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
        if (parentLabel.Text.Contains(my text))
        {
            parentLabel.Click();
            break;
        }
}
```

If you want to click the input box instead, replace `parentLabel` with `e`.

Comment: What does By.XPath("..")) mean?

Comment: @SidharthJain ".." in xpath means to go one level up, in this case to go to the parent element of your input element, which is the label element

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("mytext")).Click();
```

Comment: There are multiple occurence of "mytext" in the page, that's why I can't use By.PartialLinkText

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='checkbox']//label[contains(text(), "' + myText + '")]")).Click();